Conditional formatting date weekday only + 7 days Google Sheets
Trying to get a custom formula (other parameters besides this) to highlight a cell when it has been 7 working days since that date omitting the weekend
=TODAY()>=weekday($E8+7)
attempted to use networkdays as well but it did not work

Use WORKDAY() Function
You may try:
=WORKDAY(A1, 7) = TODAY()
to check if today is 7 business days from the specified date in cell A1.
Sample Output:

or
=WORKDAY(A1, 7) <= TODAY()
to check if it's already at least 7 business days from the specified date in cell A1.
Sample Output:

Reference:

WORKDAY


If this answer does not work for you please provide a minimal, reproducible example
